# Matrices Question invlving transpose

Tags: matrices, nilpotence, idempotents

[image]
Could anyone solve this question using properties?
I did it by taking a $2\times1$ matrix.

Comment: Is the denominator a determinant ?

Comment: As $M$ is a column-vector, the denominator is a scalar.

Comment: Yes denominator is a scalar